# jquery in virtuemart custom field

Tags: php, jquery

i'm trying to add an € symbol in a joomla virtuemart custom field.
I've found a solution as you can see here :
http://demo.magarantie.com/test.php
working.
So i'm trying to implement this in VM detail product page by adding

```
vmJsApi::addJScript('euro');
```

as you can see here :
http://demo.magarantie.com/notre-offre/formule-solo/lavage.
Ok, the script is loaded, but not working on "*prix d'achat*" custom field wich have mycustomid_31 ID..
Does anyone have an idea how to do ?

Many thanks !

**VirtueMart Version: 3.0.17.4 | Joomla! 3.6.2**

Comment: Can you post your code here rather than linking to it?

Comment: As you can see in your console the error is: $(window).load(function(){: $ is not a function. Change $ with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
(function($) {
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
if ($(this).get(0).setSelectionRange) {
  $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
} else if ($(this).get(0).createTextRange) {
  var range = $(this).get(0).createTextRange();
  range.collapse(true);
  range.moveEnd('character', pos);
  range.moveStart('character', pos);
  range.select();
}
}
}(jQuery));

$("#mycustomid_31 input").keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val().split('').pop() !== '€') {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + " €");
        $(this).setCursorPosition( $(this).val().length - 2)
    }
});
});
```